# How to wrap lines in an inline-block with CSS?

Tags: html, css-float, css

I have a simple HTML structure (**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWW8V/)**):

```
<li>
    <div class="buttons">
        <a href="done"><img src="done.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="owners">
        Даня Абрамов и Саша Васильев
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        трали-вали трали-вали трали-вали трали-вали
    </div>
</li>
```

`buttons`, `owners` and `text` have `display: inline-block`.

This looks fine when `text` is fairly small:

[image]

However, as the text grows, `inline-block` elements extend and eventually fall over the line:

[image]

This is ugly, and I would like to avoid that.
What I want to achieve instead is this:

[image]

When the text is too large to fit inside the element, I want it to be wrapped by lines.
I tried setting `float: left` on the elements, but couldn't get it working.

What's the proper way to do this with HTML and CSS (no tables)?

Comment: Use this to setup a test - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Yzmir, thanks for the suggestion. [I created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWW8V/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The exact result you desire can be achieved if you use floats instead of `display: inline-block`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/CatuS/

```
li {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.buttons, .owners {
    float: left;
}
.text {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! I guess I'll have to read about `overflow` now. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. [This](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/) is what you should read.

Comment: Learn something new every day! Thanks @thirtydot. I noticed it also works with `overflow: auto;` (at least in Safari). Perhaps that's a more desirable value?

Comment: They will usually do exactly the same thing, but in some edge cases `overflow: auto` will give unwanted crazy scrollbars. For that reason, it's best to use `hidden`.

Comment: thirtydot's link now seems to be dead - it's in the archive here https://web.archive.org/web/20150530032915/http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden

Comment: It looks like the page isn't redirecting properly. It still exists and is a great read: https://colinaarts-com.herokuapp.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify some `max-width` with percentage:

```
<li>
    <div class="buttons" style="max-width:10%;">
        <a href="done"><img src="done.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="owners" style="max-width:30%;">
        Даня Абрамов и Саша Васильев
    </div>
    <div class="text" style="max-width:60%;">
        трали-вали трали-вали трали-вали трали-вали
    </div>
</li>
<!-- 10+30+60 = 100% -->
```

Comment: As far as I know, this is the only sensible possible solution. Though you may not want to use percentages for the width.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem with this approach is [you're going to get different text widths for different rows](http://i.imgur.com/TD4hh.png) ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2BAe/)). This is very close, but I need the text to occupy all available space to the right.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very nice flexbox solution if you have the browser support:

```css
/* flexbox additions */

ul li {
  display: flex;
}

.buttons {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.owners {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

/* original CSS (inline-block is technically no longer necessary) */

.buttons {
  display: inline-block;
}

.owners {
  display: inline-block;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* the rest is visual styling */

ul li {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #DBEAFF;
  min-height: 23px;
}

.buttons {
  min-width: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}

.buttons a {
  padding: 13px 9px 5px 9px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="done"><img src="http://clstr.org/static/images/tick.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="owners">
      <a>Даня Абрамов</a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">short text
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="done"><img src="http://clstr.org/static/images/tick.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="owners">
      <a>Даня Абрамов</a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="done"><img src="http://clstr.org/static/images/tick.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="owners">
      <a>Даня Абрамов</a> и <a>Саша Васильев</a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text
      longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text longer text
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="done"><img src="http://clstr.org/static/images/tick.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="owners">
      <a>Даня Абрамов</a> и <a>Саша Васильев</a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      трали-вали трали-вали трали-вали трали-вали
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set max-width with different display mode.

```
li {overflow:hidden;}
li div { float:left; }
.button{ max-width: 10%;}
.owners{ max-width: 20%;}
.text{ max-width: 70%;}
```

[See the new result here](http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/fHwu3/1/)

BTW, if you use inline-block, the owners part won't stay on top.

I modified the code to fit your requirement. :)

FYI, `li {overflow:hidden;}` is a way to make a container to encompass its floated children.

Comment: Well, I didn't know you set the background color for li. It is a easy fix, just add li {overflow:hidden;}

Comment: Yeah, but there is another problem with `max-width` solution, as I wrote in comment to [Mat's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114367/how-to-wrap-lines-in-an-inline-block-with-css/8114418#8114418). Max-width doesn't let text take all available space, which is what I wanted.

Comment: interesting request. If so, thirtydot's solution is the one fitting your requirement. However, I think it looks weird if one of the owners is much longer than the other.

Comment: It definitely does. But the situation is, there may be one or two items out of 50 on a page that have a long text or a long list of owners. This is an exceptional situation—but I want it to be handled properly, and thirtydot's answer helps. It would definitely look awkward if multiline items were common, in which case I would need to think of a different organization of information. But they aren't common, so I'm sticking with `overflow: hidden`. Thanks for help!