# Bootstrap Inline list large amount of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I understand Bootstrap has a built in class 'list-inline'. It works great until I add a large amount of text, and then I get the following:

http://postimg.org/image/4ygjowp43/

I would like the pink div to not wrap underneath the green div. I've tried another post on stackoverflow: [How to wrap lines in an inline-block with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114367/how-to-wrap-lines-in-an-inline-block-with-css) and I cannot get floats to work.

Here is my HTML:

```
        <ul class="remove-bullet-list hanging">
            <li>
                <div class="description">
                    <b>Description: </b>
                </div>
                <div class="description-text">
                    Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text.
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.description {
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}

.description-text {
    background-color: pink;
    padding-left: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Is this you want? http://jsbin.com/lehakuyiwoya/1/edit

Comment: Kheema - Yes, but I want the text to wrap, not each line separate. It'll be a paragraph of text, not the same line over and over.

Comment: I've shared a new DEMO link, while testing the above link that was not working with IE 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/CatuS/91/)

Well, as per your requirement, `display:table` will works best.

Your style will be,

```
.description-text {
    background-color: pink;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 14px;
    width: 100%;
}
.description {
    background-color: green;        
    overflow: hidden;
}
.remove-bullet-list li {
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: that worked great! Would you recommend anything different? Is this bad practice? @Husen

Comment: @LanterneRouge not to worrry, it will work great, still if you don't add diaplay:table in the li class than you can do following , http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/h3mts0by/ but, it will not work in IE browsers, so it is advisable to use my main answer code

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

HTML

```
      <ul class="remove-bullet-list hanging">
        <li>
            <div class="col-sm-2 description">
                <b>Description: </b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 description-text">
                Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text.Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text. Large amount of text.
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
.description {
background-color: green;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
padding:0px;
}

.description-text {
    background-color: pink;
    padding:0px;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/yCWWBE0mCM

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your CSS a little bit.  You can see this works on all Browser. See **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zolazuwavano/1/edit)**.

```
.description {
background-color: green;
float: left;
}
.description-text {
  background-color: pink;
  padding-left: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:top; /* vertically align top work with display:table-cell*/

}
li{overflow: hidden;display:table;}
```

> **Note:** Here is **[another DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lehakuyiwoya/1/edit)** link which also works great but it
>   fails on IE Browser that's why I've provided another solution.